# display.launch.py --share on ROS 2 tutorials is not working - Windows 11

Tags: ros2, build, errors, urdf-tutorial, ros2-launch

I have installed ROS 2 (Humble Hawksbill) on windows 11 and trying to follow [URDF tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/URDF/Building-a-Visual-Robot-Model-with-URDF-from-Scratch.html). When I run the folllwing command:

```
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model: =`ros2 pkg prefix --share urdf_tutorial`/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

I get the error below:[image]

```
 C:\dev\ros2_ws>ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=`ros2 pkg prefix --share urdf_tutorial`/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
usage: ros2 [-h] [--use-python-default-buffering]
            Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...
ros2: error: unrecognized arguments: --share urdf_tutorial`/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
```

I installed the package from here: https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial and then copy pasted it in my overlay src folder "C:/dev/ros2_ws/src. Any guidence or leads would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
Three things: 1) Which verison of ROS you are using? 2) Tell us the commands you used for installing the tutorial package. 3) Share the output of following command: `ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py --show-arguments`

Comment: I am using Ros 2 - Humble Hawksbill

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... copy the text and paste it into your post and format same as the other two snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ros2 pkg prefix --share`
and type directly:

```
C:\dev\ros2_ws>ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:='src/urdf_tutorial`/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
```

Pay attention to use the right path to your file `01-myfirst.urdf`
And be sure you are using the right quotes ''